# Totaling Hierarchical Data in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am working with a complicated hierarchy of parts for a manufacturing company at the moment, and I need to create group totals. I can't just deal with leafs because some of the intermediate parts are sold as well as being used to manufacture a further product. The basis of my query so far is as follows:

```
    select rownum, level, part, qty
    from <table>
    where <param>
    START WITH <component#>
    CONNECT BY prior <part#> = <component#>
```

This gives me a table where a branch can be separated from its root because other branches exist. How can I duplicate the roots so that I can have complete hierarchy lists? If this isn't possible, then the next best solution would be to have a running total that looks back and finds the last part of the hierarchy OR a product of each complete hierarchy.

Example data:

> ```
> Level | Part | Qty Used | Sales
>
> 1     | a    | 2        | Y
> 2     | b    | 1        | N 
> 3     | c    | 5        | Y 
> 2     | d    | 6        | Y 
> 3     | e    | 5        | N
> 4     | f    | 2        | Y 
> 3     | g    | 3        | Y 
> 1     | h    | 6        | N 
> 2     | i    | 3        | Y
> ```

Required Result:

> ```
> Sales Part | Qty Product
>
> a          | 2
> c          | 10
> d          | 60
> f          | 120
> g          | 36
> i          | 18
> ```

Only Sales Parts are returned with the product of all quantities in the hierarchy strand leading to them.

Comment: You could use a Common table expression to take the output of your hierarchy and create a running total as illustrated in #5 in following https://community.oracle.com/thread/1033922?tstart=0 (With tableName as your query running total query syntax)

Comment: I don't really understand, could you please prepare either CTE or scripts or sqlfiddle to give us input and show us the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't see how this will work for me. Maybe I haven't fully understood the query you've posted a link too, but when I try something like this it groups all the parts based on whether they have the same root, but I don't want this. They may have the same root, but be in different hierarchical strands.

I've also realised that I need to find the product (not the total) so I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Hi zaratustra. I've added more detail, but I couldn't find a way to add a table and I'm not able to post pictures yet due to my rep level. So I'm sorry - it looks awful!